Resource Estimation with Stim
To implement the Splitting method in an architecture using Stim and PyMatching for resource estimation at low error rates ( $10^{-6}$ ), where Monte Carlo simulation is ineffective, I recently found a relevant paper and its associated GitHub repository. This paper utilizes an importance sampling method. I would like to inquire if there is a class in Stim that supports this approach.
Thank you!

If $10^{-6}$ is the logical error rate, Monte Carlo simulation might work perfectly fine. For example, Stim's getting started notebook measures a 10^-7 logical error rate; it takes less than a minute. If it's the physical error rate... then you might have a problem measuring the logical error rate.

Sorry for not specifying earlier; I meant the physical error rate. I implemented the Metropolis algorithm with the splitting method, but it does not guarantee results. I then found a paper on importance sampling and am now trying to find a method for it.

Ah, in that case you definitely can't use Monte Carlo. What is the code distance of the construction? If it's 3 or 5 you can sometimes get away with explicit enumeration of all logical errors.
